# how to do the following using loop in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

### getting it from a form

```
$q1=$_POST["ques1"];
$q2=$_POST["RadioGroup1"];
$q3=$_POST["RadioGroup2"];
$q4=$_POST["RadioGroup3"];
$q5=$_POST["RadioGroup4"];
```

### Creating an array

```
$questions=array();
```

## how to do this using loop ?

```
$questions[1]=$q1;
$questions[2]=$q2;
$questions[3]=$q3;
$questions[4]=$q4;
$questions[5]=$q5;
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 1; isset(${"q$i"}); $i++)
    $questions[$i] = ${"q$i"};
```

See also http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Nothing, this is the correct answer, the question did not follow the community guidelines and I guess someone didn't like you breaking ranks. Whatever, I gave you one to make it even again.

Comment: @JRL Thanks, but I think that I wouldn't know what to search for without knowing about variable vars...